# Write-Host stopped working except under certain conditions

Tags: powershell

I've done something to my script that has changed the default behavior of `Write-Host`, but I can't figure out what exactly. I'm stumbling from article to article trying to learn 15 years worth of powershell "features"/gotchas and am having no luck. My scripts primary purpose is for creating a re-usable, interactive menu system, so the output to the Host is important and not an after thought.

What are the obvious/not obvious things I can check that would alter Write-Host's behavior?

```
Write-Host "howdy" # doesn't output anything anymore
Write-Host "howdy" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan # works for any color
Write-Host "howdy" | Out-Host # works

&docker build -f $($dockerfile.FullName) --force-rm -t $dockerTag $dockerBuildContext *>&1 | out-host # works
&docker build -f $($dockerfile.FullName) --force-rm -t $dockerTag $dockerBuildContext *>&1 # doesn't output anything anymore
```

I do have a function in the script for adding color to text, but even with that disabled I still have the same problem, so it must be something else.

```
function AddTextColor($message, $colorCode) {
    $escapeChar = [char]27;
    # disabled for now
    # "$escapeChar[$($colorCode)m$($message)${escapeChar}[0m"
    return $message;
}
```

I was forced to recently change my coding style to assign `$null`'s to function calls that return objects so they wouldn't be output to the Host. I feel like this has something to do with it, but if I revert to the old way, then I'll just have garbage output to the Host everywhere which makes the menu system I'm creating useless.

```
$null = AddMenuItem @{ ParentMenu = $knownUrisSubMenu; } # new coding style to prevent the object returned from the function from being written to the host
AddMenuItem @{ ParentMenu = $knownUrisSubMenu; } # old coding sytle, which I prefer, but produces host output
```

Comment: `Write-Host "howdy" # doesn't output anything anymore`, I presume checked whether the background color isn' t th same as the foreground color...

Comment: What does `Get-Command Write-Host -All` show?

Comment: @iRon I don't think it has the same bg/fg color. Because there would a pure black line where the output would be, but there is nothing.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it is `Cmdlet  Write-Host  7.0.0.0  Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`. I had this problem a day ago on powershell 5.1, and just today upgraded to powershell 7.2, but same problem.

Comment: If have this same problem on 5.1 and 7 it sounds more like a Code Editor problem rather than a PowerShell issue itself. Does `pwsh.exe -c 'Write-Host howdy; Read-Host'` and `powershell.exe -c 'Write-Host howdy; Read-Host'` produce any output if you run both from Windows Key > Run

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon the code is being executed from a standard powershell prompt, not from within an IDE/Editor.

Comment: The multiple issues are because `Write-Host` is not notorious for causing issues when redirecting streams or piping. [Some details in Write-Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-information?view=powershell-7.2) -- `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host 'hi world'` will output text on `WIndowsPowershell 5` as well as `Powershell 7.2` -- Using Write-Information you can use any color, and won't need to use `$null -eq function` because the caller can change `-InformationAction Continue` to ignore

Comment: Without that, you're still able to use `AddMenuItem @{ ParentMenu = $knownUrisSubMenu; } | Out-Null` -- Part of the problem may be misunderstanding output is implicit, so `return $message;` is misleading. It's hard to summarize in a tiny single-line commet